# emacs visual highlight to rg (ripgrep)

Tags: emacs

I'm almost through adding features from spacemacs to a hand rolled emacs config, but can't figure out how to replicate spacemacs feature of highlighting a term to search for in the page (i've replicated this using evil-viusual-star) and then sending that highlight to counsel-rg.

For non-spacemacs users the workflow is:
(i'm using evil-mode)

1. In command mode press v, highlight a term
2. Shift + 8 to search in the buffer for that term
3. / to recursively search files in the current directory for search term (using counsel-rg)

Has anyone implemented sending highlighted term to counsel-rg in their config?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked to see how spacemacs is doing it?

Comment: i tried but got lost in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`thing-at-point` will return the highlighted word that you can pass to `counsel-rg`.

```lisp
(defun my-search ()
  (interactive)
  (counsel-rg (thing-at-point 'word t)))
```